# Scala error handling: Try or Either?

Tags: scala, error-handling

Given a method in UserService: `update`, what's the best way to handle errors/exceptions here?

#### Option A:

```
def update(...): Try[User]
```

In this way, I need to define my **custom exceptions** and throw them in the function body when needed. Most of these exceptions are business errors (e.g. user_id cannot be changed, etc). The point here is no matter what exception(s) are thrown (business error, network exception, DB IO exception, etc), treat them the same way and just return a `Failure(err)` - let the upper layer handle them.

#### Option B:

```
def update(...): Either[Error, User]
```

This is the exception-free way. In the function body it catches all possible exceptions and turns them into Error, and for business errors just return `Left[Error]`.

Using `Try` seems to be a more natural way to me as I want to handle errors. `Either` is a more generic thing - `Either[Error, T]` is just one special case and I think `Try` is invented for this special case. But I also read that we should avoid using exceptions for error handling...

So, which solution is better, and why?

Comment: I'd prefer `Either`, because it allows you to be explicit about which error types are possible, rather than the generic `Throwable`  you get with `Try`. As @Gabriele says, I'd prefer scalaz `\/` as it has a more usable `map` construct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no silver bullet.

As you noted already, `Try` is simply a more specialized version of `Either`, where the `Left` type is fixed to `Throwable`.

`Try` might be a good fit if you need to materialize exceptions thrown by external (perhaps java) libraries, as its constructor automatically catches them.

Another advantage of `Try` is that it has `map` and `flatMap`, so you can use it directly in for-comprehensions, whereas with `Either` you would have to explicitly project on the `right` case.
Anyway, there's plenty of alternative implementations with a "right-bias", and probably the scalaz `\/` type is the most popular one.

That being said, I typically use `\/` or the almost equivalent `Validation` (both from scalaz), as I like having the ability of returning errors that do not extend `Throwable`.

It also allows for more precise error types, which is a huge win.