# When to use Option/Some/None over preconditions

Tags: scala, preconditions

I'm writing a small package and am unsure whether I should be flagging unsupported behavior with preconditions such as `require`, or if I should be returning `None`.  Is there a preferred style?

As an example, I have a method that partitions an increasing interval [a, b] into 4 pieces:

```
def increasingPartition(a: Double, b: Double): Vector[Double] = {
  for (i <- Vector.range(0, 5)) yield {
    a + i * (b - a) / 5
  }
}
```

If this function is called with `a >= b`, it should not calculate the partition since it will not be increasing.  What's the best way to express this behavior?

Option 1:

```
def increasingPartition(a: Double, b: Double): Vector[Double] = {
  require(a < b, f"$a is not less than $b")
  for (i <- Vector.range(0, 5)) yield {
    a + i * (b - a) / 5
  }
}
```

Option 2:

```
def increasingPartition(a: Double, b: Double): Option[Vector[Double]] = {
  if (a >= b) {
    None
  } else {
    val partition = for (i <- Vector.range(0, 5)) yield {
      a + i * (b - a) / 5
    }
    Some(partition)
  }
}
```

Comment: Rather use validation type

Comment: It mostly depends on how do you expect your users to use your function. Remember `require` means that you would actually throw an **exception** if the condition is not meet, you can think of it as a strong error in the program. On the other hand, **Option** would mean that it is a logical error and your users should always deal with it. A third option _(as mentioned by @cchantep)_ would be to use **refined types** to actually forbid this to compile.

Comment: Might want to consider [Try or Either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27171213/scala-error-handling-try-or-either)

Comment: Thank you all for the food for thought.  Part of my uncertainty about which direction to take is because I will likely have many nested functions in this package.  I started off using Some/Option/None, but that caused a lot of boilerplate code to appear in methods higher in the call stack.  There is some good discussion in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-user/SpSMvIFLY_w/JKeRFAc-ucIJ) about using Exceptions vs Try or Either

Comment: Handling the exception is going to result in boilerplate too. I find the functional programming idioms are more concise and principled.